# Reference to non-existent field 'd'

Tags: matlab

My mat file contains 40,000 rows and two columns. I have to read it line by line 
and then get values of last column in a single row.
Following is my code:

```
       for v = 1:40000

             firstRowB = data.d(v,:)

            if(firstRowB(1,2)==1)
               count1=count1+1;
            end
            if(firstRowB(1,2)==2)
               count2=count2+1;
            end

         end
```

FirstRowB gets the row checks whether last column equals 1 or 2 and then increases the value of respective count by 1.

But I keep getting this error:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'd'.
```

Comment: What you get if you type `fieldnames(data)`? Or `class(data)`?

Comment: This is what I get ans =  'data'

Comment: using class(data)-- struct

Comment: Ok. And `fieldnames(data.data)`?

Comment: Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of type
'double'.

Comment: I think that you just need to change `d` in your code to `data`. So the line will be: `firstRowB = data.data(v,:)` .  Check it

Comment: It worked... thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use vectorization (it is always convenient especially in Matlab). Taking advantage of the fact that true is one and false is zero, if you just want to count you can do :

```
count1 = sum ( data.d(:, 2) == 1 ) ;
count2 = sum (data.d(:,2) == 2 ) ;
```

in fact in general you could define :

```
getNumberOfElementsInLastColEqualTo = @(numb) sum (data.d(:,end) == numb ) ;

counts =arrayfun( getNumberOfElementsInLastColEqualTo  , [1 2 ] );
```

Hope this helps.